# why there are 2 filesize functions in PHP (filesize() and SplFileInfo::getSize)?

Tags: php

I'm sorry this might be ridicules question but I have been using [filesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) for my 4 months of php coding *(I'm new to php)* and I always think of it as  the php standard library function for getting a file size. but now I was reading about [Standard PHP Library (SPL)](http://php.net/book.spl) and I surprised that there is another function called [SplFileInfo::getSize](http://php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getsize.php) which do exactly the same thing

1. Is `filesize()` considered a standard php function or not ?
2. If `filesize()` considered a standard php  function , why the php creators bother themselves by making another function(`SplFileInfo::getSize`) do the same thing?
3. What is the difference between both functions `filesize()` and `SplFileInfo::getSize` ? which one should I use?

*please note that I'm new to php* . thanks

Comment: What are the arguments for both functions?

Comment: @u_mulder `filesize()` takes the file name string, and the other takes no argument(a static function), so ?

Comment: Isn't it a difference?

Comment: `SplFileInfo` is an added extension. PHP has a lot of similar functions. Asking `why the php creators bother` is going to lead to opinion based answers.

Comment: @u_mulder does this mean this is the ONLY difference ? if the programmer comfortable with the the argument style he uses `filesize()` if not, he uses the other one ?

Comment: Also `getSize()` is called from instance of `SplFileInfo`.

Comment: @chris85 No, I mean `filesize()`. I use it to get the file size. why there is another function in the standard library do the same exact thing ?

Comment: @u_mulder do you mean, this is just for the library users comfortability?

Comment: SPL is much later than the basic filesize function; and SPLFileInfo provides access to a lot of different aspects of file information all in one place that aren't all accessible from basic functions, and it would be stupid for it to give everything but file size

Comment: @MarkBaker thaaanks. I got it. so `filesize ` is called a **basic function**, and SPL is complete library added to php later. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Is `filesize()` considered a standard php function or not ?

What is meant by `standard`? As I see in a manual `filesize()` exists since php4 (which didn't support OOP in a proper way). So, this function is a procedural way of getting a filesize. You need only path to file and what you get is a size. And nothing else.

2. If `filesize()` considered a standard php function , why the php creators bother themselves by making another function `SplFileInfo::getSize` do the same thing?

In php5 (as you can see `getSize` is available since php5) more object oriented features had been added to php, they all are part of Standard PHP Library or `SPL`. So, in php5 you can consider a file like an object with properties - name, size etc. So for getting one property or another - there's a method. For getting filesize is `getSize()`

So, `getSize` is not a function, it's a method of a class `SplFileInfo`.

3. What is the difference between both functions `filesize()` and `SplFileInfo::getSize()`? which one should I use?

As we already learned - `filesize()` uses a procedural approach:

```
$filename = '/path/to/file.ext';
$size = filesize($filename);
```

And as `getSize()` is a method of a class, object of a class should be created first:

```
$filename = '/path/to/file.ext';
$finfo_obj = new SplFileInfo($filename);
$size = $finfo_obj->getSize();
```

So, it's up to you to decide **what** function and **which** approach to use.